# Opengl - make specific VBO not draw in specific screen area ("inverse" of GL_SCISSORS_TEST )

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to make a specific VBO (vertex buffer object) to not be drawn in specific screen area (but be drawn in the rest of the screen).

I have two VBOs that must be drawn in the screen. They can appear independently, parts of VBO1 overlap VBO2 and VBO1 has priority over VBO2. When both objects are being drawn, I want VBO2 to not render in the overlap area, but render the rest of object. Since the size of VBO2 can change, trying to achieve this behaviour with EBOs (element buffer objects) can be tricky.

In some sense, what i am looking for is the inverse of GL_SCISSORS_TEST. If in GL_SCISSORS_TEST I can define an area where the symbol can only de drawn inside (and the part that is outside is clipped), I want to be able to define an area where a symbol will not be drawn inside (but the part of the symbol that is outside the area will be drawn).

Which strategies would be best to achieve this in Opengl?

Comment: Can't you simply achieve what you want by rendering VBO2 first, then VBO1? The second draw call will override all pixels in the overlap region anyway. More details about the shapes your are rendering would also be useful: Do you only have rectangles (as hinted by scissor testing), or do you have general 2d polygons, or full 3D meshes?

Comment: Can't you use a [stencil buffer](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing)?

Comment: @BDL, I can't really only draw them in different order. I also need to make sure there is a "space" between symbols, to improve readability.  The objects are in 2D (usually rendered with GL_TRIANGLES). But there is also Text rendered with FreeType. There are no 3D meshes.

Comment: @LCC: So the shape where you don't want to render isn't exactly the same as the shape in VBO1? Where is the information stored about which region to exclude?

Comment: @BDL, yes, it is not exactly since I want to improve readability between different symbols. I know the areas I can't render beforehand, since I know the position and size of VBO1, and it only needs to be slightly bigger than that. I believe G.M. suggestion is a great one. I am currently looking into that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways how the desired result can be achieved:

For the general case, the [stencil test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Stencil_Test) seems to be a good option. Note, that your framebuffer needs to support stencil buffering.

- Clear stencil buffer with 0
- Draw VBO1 with the following settings which set the stencil buffer to 1 for all pixels covered by VBO1. If you need a larger range than just VBO1, consider rendering a special stencil shape with color writing disabled that marks the non-drawable area.

  - glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF),
  - glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE)
- Draw VBO2 with following settings which only draw VBO2 where the stencil buffer has a value of 0 (aka, where VBO1 has not drawn):

  - glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 0xFF),
  - glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

If the VBOs contain only 2-dimensional objects parallel to the screen plane (like sprites), then you could also use depth testing and render VBO2 further away than VBO1.

If you have a more specialized case like rectangles  (as suggested by siccor testing which only works on rectangular areas), it is also an option to pass the boundary of the VBO1 rectangle to the fragment shader of VBO2 and discard fragments if they fall inside the boundary area.